# Detecting collisions on a scrolling game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

How does one have a scrolling map and detect collision on it?

I have tried a tile map but dont want to use this technique.

I would like to learn how a games background can be scrolled as well as object are detected for collision.

One example would be [this game](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/astronut/id336015305?mt=8).

If one is not using tilemaps for this, how is the world scrollable as well as having physical objects detecting collision with the character sprite?

Please point me in the right direction on this topic.

Comment: The technique should be essentially the same with or without a tilemap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple collision detection is done by checking to see if bounding boxes (or sometimes, bounding circles) overlap.  That is, given object A and object B, if their bounding boxes overlap, then a collision has occurred.

If you want to get fancy, you create polygons for your objects and determine if the bounding polygons overlap.  That's more complicated and harder to get right, and also involves considerably more processing.

It's not really much different from using a tilemap.  With a tilemap, you're doing collision detection against the tiles.  Without a tilemap you're doing collision detection against the bounding boxes of individual objects.  The logic is almost identical.

Additional info:

I think the problem you're struggling with is that you're thinking in terms of screens.  It's important when writing a game to separate the concept of the game world (the model) from the presentation (the screen).

For example, a simple side scroller game might consist of many "screens" full of information.  Whereas the screen might be 1000 units wide, the game's world could be 10,000 or 100,000 units wide.  Note that I say "units" rather than "pixels".  A game's unit of measure could be inches, centimeters, miles, or whatever.  All of your game logic should work in terms of world coordinates.  How you project that onto the view (the screen) is irrelevant to what goes on in the world.

Every object in the world is assigned a position *in world coordinates*.  That includes the player sprite, which is moving around in the world.  All collision detection and other interaction of objects in the world is done in terms of world coordinates.

To simplify things, assume that there is a one-to-one mapping between world units and screen units.  That is, your world is 10,000 pixels wide, and your screen is 1,000 pixels wide.  The world, then is "ten screens" in size.  More correctly, the screen can view 1/10 of the world.  If that's the case, then your view can be defined by the left-most world coordinate that's visible.  So if the world coordinate 2,000 is at the left of your screen, the rightmost column of pixels on your screen will be world coordinate 2,999.

This implies that you need world-to-screen and screen-to-world transformation functions.  For this case, those functions are very simple.  If we assume that there's no vertical scrolling, then only the x coordinate needs to be transformed by subtracting the world x coordinate from the view x coordinate.  That is, `world.x - viewOrigin.x`.  So in the case above, the screen coordinate of an object that's at world x coordinate 2,315 would be (2,315 - 2,000), or 315.  That's the x coordinate of the object's position on the screen.  In the current view.

The screen-to-world is the opposite:  add the object's screen coordinate to the view's origin:  315 + 2,000 = 2,315.

I can't stress how important it is to maintain this separation between world and view coordinates.  All of your game logic should operate in terms of world coordinates.  You update the view to show you what's happening in the world.  In a side scroller, you typically move the view left and right based on the player's actions.  If the player moves left, you move the view origin left.  If the player moves right, you move the view origin to the right.

Once you internalize this idea, things become much simpler.  Everything done in the game world happens *in the world*.  You make sure that the world state is consistent, and then you worry about displaying a view of the world.

There's no easier way (that I know of) to build a game that's larger than the screen.  No matter how you build it, you have to have some concept of showing just part of the world on the view.  By formalizing it, you separate the presentation from the game logic and things get much, much simpler.

Comment: Ok great. My confusion is on the fact that in a tile map the objects are pre placed and set as collision objects. Then as the scroll occurs the objects(consisting of tiles) are checked. The so called area is known. How is this known when not using tilemaps? What if one have a e.g. fence which is in the graphic and should be collidable. How is this set in the code rather than using the tilemap. The tile map allows a predrawn environment, game area to be marked as collidable. e.g. mario. The ledges and floors are pre known. How would this be setup in the code using the positions?

Comment: You create your objects and set their position, and place them in a list of collision objects. Whenever you want to check for collisions, you check against that list of objects. It's not fundamentally different from checking for collisions with tiles. I think there's something more fundamental that you're trying to ask, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: So when the list of collisions is created, what positions are used? Does one take the entire area of positions, e.g. an area of 3 iphone screens, and place an objects position to a position in the 3rd screen e.g (160, 1050) or does one use only one screens positions(160, 70)? How does one then track the screen in use and spawn objects accordingly? Then my other question is, what if it is not a spawnable object and a fixed object, how does one get the exact positions to detect for collisions? What if an object spans over a number of screens, what positions are used?Thanks, Im a little confused.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. I would give more +1s. ;) So my final question is how are these exact positions added in the code, if the image is created outside without tiles? Would the coordinates just be copied from the creating tools coordinates? what about rounded objects or oddly shaped objects?

Comment: Im not sure if you are fimiliar with cocos2d. It has a limit on the tilemap size of 2048x2048. is there a limit on image size if tilemaps are not used. How are these defined areas linked to the measurements used on the game world without using tilemaps. Would one use pixels? Can game worlds just be plain pngs? And then the x and y coordinates must be mapped to this?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to set you camera dimensions to the dimensions of your level that you want to be rendered. You can get the level coordinates according to whatever you camera is supposed to be fixed on, say your hero.
Sprite collision is relatively easy. Use the two sprites' height/width you're testing against (IDK about cocos2d, but most api's sprites' position are at the upper left corner of the sprite):

```
if(player.Pos.x <= (object.Pos.x + object.width) || (player.Pos.x + player.width) >= object.Pos.x)
{
    if(player.Pos.y >= (object.Pos.y - object.height) || (player.Pos.y - player.height) <= object.Pos.y)
        //collision detected
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The collision part I am ok with. my problem is the concept of the actual gaming area. how does one handle spawning or detecting collision on objects in of game area still to be scrolled into the scene/camera view? Also what if an image is pre created e.g. a bunch of rocks or a mountain range which is present throughout the game area as the new area comes into view. How would this mountain range be set as an object and its current spacing it covers be modified as the camera views on it? does this make sense? :)

Comment: This is somewhat a broad topic that has several solutions. It depends on how you design your game engine, really. You can read in level objects from file (xml or .txt or w/e..), store/retrieve any information you need like position, sprite filepath, etc. When you load each level, load it's objects into memory, and free up the last level's memory. Do your collision against objects in camera view. Hope this gives you some ideas :)